# Failed to compile Node-sass not working error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I am trying to run an already made react.js project.

I have installed `npm install` already.

But I am facing an error every time.

`./src/assets/base.scss (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/assets/base.scss) Error: Can't resolve './components/icons/components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.eot' in '/home/arsalan/Desktop/libra/FrontEnd-main/src/assets'`

I have already done the research and already done the following solutions.

1. Uninstall and reinstall node-sass

   ```
     npm uninstall node-sass;

     npm install node-sass@4.14.1
   ```

From this URL [Stack overflow URL related to my error][1]

2. Rebuild of node-sass

   ```
     npm rebuild node-sass
   ```
3. Remove node_module and reinstall it

   ```
    remove node_modules folder and run npm install
   ```

from this URL [Stack overflow URL related to my error][2]

Also tried the following.

```
npm install --save node-sass
```

But none of these worked for me. Can anyone guide me where I am wrong?

Comment: Can you please check out my answer and let me know if it solves your problem?

Comment: @robertp no it doesn't help me out.

Comment: OK. Have you installed the npm package, or just updated your Webpack config file? Can you share your Webpack config with us?

Comment: @robertp I have edited my question and added the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Can't resolve
> './components/icons/components/icons/linearicons/Linearicons-Free.eot'

You seem like you don't declare those files with using webpack plugin, file-loader or url-loader.

Maybe like this

In your webpack.config.js, at module.loaders, you must append this code :

```
{ test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
```

Comment: I did not get module.loader in webpack.config.js

Comment: If no exists before, you must add it self. You can follow webpack doc below:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with Sass or your package installation, but Sass not being able to resolve the relative path to the font files. You need to add a loader called `resolve-url-loader` to help Sass to resolve the font URLs. We don't know what your Webpack file looks like (or what version of Webpack you are using), but with Webpack 4 or 5 it should be similar to this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        'resolve-url-loader', // add this before sass-loader
        'sass-loader',
    ]
},
```

Once you add the `resolve-url-loader` webpack loader, yous Sass files should be able to load the font files.

You'll need to install the npm package with:

```
npm install resolve-url-loader --save-dev
```

Here is a note on this in the Webpack docs for `sass-loader`: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#problems-with-url.